# How to properly use an oracle in the request, the "If" and "LIKE" condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i need help with the code, i have two pieces of code that write two variables: v_responsible_job and v_responsible.I would like to combine these queries into one and add a condition if.

If the answer to this query is "ABC", then the first query must be completed, and if not,the second query:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ce28fad7e33f00c5538e49943ae7dechere is the demo data

```
SELECT NAME FROM data_separators WHERE id = way.DS_ID
```

example answer:

```
NAME

ABC Info
Scool
offise
ABC SHOP
```

first call :

```
BEGIN
  SELECT full_name, job INTO v_responsible, job_id
    FROM physical_persons
    WHERE id IN (SELECT physical_person
                   FROM data_separators WHERE id = way.DS_ID) AND rownum = 1;

  SELECT name
    INTO v_responsible_job
    FROM jobs
    WHERE id = job_id AND
          rownum = 1;

  if v_responsible_job is not null then
    if length(v_responsible_job) > 0 then
      v_responsible_job := ', '|| v_responsible_job;
    end if;
  end if;
     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
           v_responsible_job := '';
     END;
```

second call :

```
  BEGIN
  SELECT full_name, job
    INTO v_responsible, job_id
    FROM physical_persons
    WHERE id IN (SELECT RESPONSIBLE
                   FROM ADRESSES
                   WHERE name = p1.name) AND
          rownum = 1;

  SELECT name
    INTO v_responsible_job
    FROM jobs
    WHERE id = job_id AND 
          rownum = 1;

  if v_responsible_job is not null then
    if length(v_responsible_job) > 0 then
      v_responsible_job := ', '|| v_responsible_job;
    end if;
  end if;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
           v_responsible_job := '';
     END;
```

my varianr answer , but his don't work(

```html
         BEGIN
   
           select count(*)  into  v_count_word FROM data_separators WHERE id = way.DS_ID and  NAME LIKE '%ABC%';
           select count(RESPONSIBLE)  into  v_count_respon FROM ADRESSES WHERE name = p1.name;
           
         if v_count_word > 0 then       
             SELECT full_name, job INTO v_responsible, job_id FROM physical_persons WHERE id IN (SELECT physical_person FROM data_separators WHERE id = way.DS_ID) AND rownum = 1;
             SELECT name INTO v_responsible_job FROM jobs WHERE id = job_id AND rownum = 1;
             if v_responsible_job is not null then
                if length(v_responsible_job) > 0 then
                v_responsible_job := ', '|| v_responsible_job;
                end if;
             end if;
          end if; 


          if v_count_respon > 0 and  v_count_word = 0 then
           SELECT full_name, job INTO v_responsible, job_id FROM physical_persons WHERE id IN (SELECT RESPONSIBLE
                   FROM ADRESSES
                   WHERE name = p1.name) AND rownum = 1;

           SELECT name INTO v_responsible_job FROM jobs  WHERE id = job_id AND rownum = 1;

                      if v_responsible_job is not null then
                        if length(v_responsible_job) > 0 then
                          v_responsible_job := ', '|| v_responsible_job;
                        end if;
                      end if;
        end if;                              
        if      v_count_respon = 0 and v_count_word  = 0 then   
             SELECT full_name, job INTO v_responsible, job_id FROM physical_persons WHERE id IN (SELECT physical_person FROM data_separators WHERE id = way.DS_ID) AND rownum = 1;
             SELECT name INTO v_responsible_job FROM jobs WHERE id = job_id AND rownum = 1;
             if v_responsible_job is not null then
                if length(v_responsible_job) > 0 then
                v_responsible_job := ', '|| v_responsible_job;
                end if;
             end if;
        end if;
         EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
             v_responsible_job := '-';
   END;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff everything is simple, I have a query where I look for a name, if the answer (to that name) does not have "ABC" then I want my variables to be written from the second query and if it is "ABC" then my variables are written to first requestt

Comment: Don't catch the `OTHERS` exception. You should just catch the exceptions you want to handle like `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff look for a nod to my version of the species view

Answer (score 0):

Combine the first two queries using `EXISTS` and then use `LISTAGG` to aggregate the values:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_responsible_jobs VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY name )
  INTO   v_responsible_jobs
  FROM   jobs j
  WHERE  EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   physical_persons pp
    WHERE  pp.job_id = j.job_id
    AND    id IN (
      SELECT physical_person
      FROM   data_separators
      WHERE  id = way.DS_ID
    )
  );
END;
/
```

An other way would be to use `BULK COLLECT INTO` a collection data type and then to iterate over the collection concatenating the string; but that is more complicated than using `LISTAGG` to do all the work for you.

Comment: thank you, but almost did not understand your example, where in the code am I looking for "ABC"? can you show me an example which is more advanced?

Comment: @MaksIngenr Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60951913/edit) your example to include a [MRE] including the DDL statements for your tables and some sample data. All I have done is to adapt your code, if you want more then you are going to have to help us to help you by providing enough information that we can provide a better answer.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ce28fad7e33f00c5538e49943ae7dechere is the demo data

Comment: is this data enough?

Comment: look for a nod to my version of the species view